# Object does not match when i pass value in navigation, Xamarin Forms

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, navigation, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

I Try To Navigate from ListView Page The List View Return Data From Sqlit 
The Code Below from firt Page when I select from ListView :
Xaml Code :

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="FirstTestApp.AllTripsPage"
         Title="AllTrips">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

        <ListView x:Name="TripsList" ItemSelected="TripsList_ItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5,5,5,5">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Medium" />
                       </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

C# Function :

```
private async void TripsList_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            return;
            //ItemSelected is called on deselection, 
            //which results in SelectedItem being set to null
        }
        var Selected = (Trip)e.SelectedItem;

      await  Navigation.PushAsync(new ShowTrip(Selected));

    }
```

this Code in Page ShowTrip which it view some details about item I choice:
 xaml Code :

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="FirstTestApp.ShowTrip"
         Title="Trip Details">
<ContentView.Content>
    <Label Text="Trip Details" />
        <Label Text="Name" />
        <Label  Text ="{Binding Name}" />
        <Label  Text="Description" />
        <Label  Text ="{Binding Description}"/>
        <Label  Text="Done:" />
    <Label  Text ="{Binding Done}"/>
</ContentView.Content>
```

C#:

```
public partial class ShowTrip : ContentPage
{
    Trip SelectTrip;
    public ShowTrip(Trip Selected)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        SelectTrip = Selected;
        BindingContext = SelectTrip;
    }

}
```

The Error Appear in  InitializeComponent() Function :

```
 private void InitializeComponent() {
        this.LoadFromXaml(typeof(ShowTrip));///in This Line Exception happened 
    }
```

**The error is :"Object does not match target type"**

Comment: Looks like some error in XAML, post you XAML code, please.

Comment: @EgorGromadskiy  I Edited it

Comment: Try to use `StackLayout` instead of `<ContentView.Content>` on `ShowTrip` page.

Comment: yeaah , its working thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `StackLayout` instead of `<ContentView.Content>` on `ShowTrip` page.